# Named entity recognition with preset list of names for Python / PHP

Tags: php, python, text, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to process a CSV file that has as in each row a text field with the name of organization and position of an individual within that organization as unstructured text.  This field is usually a mess of text like this:

```
Assoc. Research Professor  Dept. Psychology  Univ. California  Santa Barbara
```

I need to pull out the position and the organization name.  For the position, I use preg_match for a series of about 60 different regular expressions for the different professions, and I think it works pretty well (my guess is that it catches about 80%).  But, I'm having trouble catching the organization name. I have a MySQL table with roughly 16,000 organization names that I can perform a simple preg_match for, but due to common misspellings and abbreviations, it's only catching about 30% of the organizations.  For example, my database has

```
University of California Santa Barbara
```

But the CSV file might have any of the options:

```
Univ Cal Santa Barbara
University Cal-Santa Barbara
University California-Santa Barbara
Cal University, Santa Barbara
```

I need to process several hundred thousand records, and I can't spend the time to correct 70% of the records that are currently not being processed correctly or painstakingly create multiple aliases for each organization. What I would like to be able to do is to catch small differences (such as the small misspellings, hyphens versus spaces, and common abbreviations), and, if still no matches are found, to ideally recognize an organizational name and create a new record for it.

- What libraries or tools in Python or PHP would allow to perform a similarity match that would have a broader reach?
- Would NLTK in Python catch misspellings?
- Is it possible to use AlchemyAPI to catch misspelled organizations?  So far I've only been able to use it to catch correctly spelled organizations
- Since I'm comparing a short string (the organization name) to a longer string (that includes the name plus extraneous information) is there any hope in using PHP's similar_text function?

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is within the domain of fuzzy logic. See if these are of any help:

http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/119-Neural-Networks-in-PHP.html

http://ann.thwien.de/index.php/Installation

Comment: Thanks for pointing those resources out. I'm not familiar with neural networks, but I'll try to dig into this and see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use [`difflib`](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) to calculate the similarity ratio between the CSV input and the canonical spelling, and consider it a match if it's above a certain threshold (say, 0.65).

For example:

```
import difflib

exact = 'University of California Santa Barbara'

inputs = ['Univ Cal Santa Barbara',
          'University Cal-Santa Barbara',
          'University California-Santa Barbara',
          'Cal University, Santa Barbara',
          'Canterbury University']

sm = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, exact)
ratios = []
for input in inputs:
    sm.set_seq2(input)
    ratios.append(sm.ratio())

print ratios
```

gives:

```
[0.73333333333333328, 0.81818181818181823, 0.93150684931506844,
 0.71641791044776115, 0.33898305084745761]
```

Note how 'Canterbury University' has a much lower match ratio() than the inputs you gave.

Then again, SequenceMatcher.ratio() may be too slow computed over 16,000 values.